# Gradle 8:':publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository' uses this output of task ':bundleReleaseAar' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency

Tags: android-library, gradlew, maven-publish

I had this issue when I updated my gradle-wrapper to use Gradle 8.0. I had this two errors:

```
1. Task ':publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository' uses this output of task ':androidSourcesJar' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.

2. Task ':publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository' uses this output of task ':bundleReleaseAar' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
```

My `build.gradle` file looked like this.

```
buildscript {
    ...
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs
    classifier "sources"
}

version = '8.0.0'
android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
}

android.libraryVariants.all {
    def aptOutputDir = new File(buildDir, "generated/source/apt/${it.unitTestVariant.dirName}")
    it.unitTestVariant.addJavaSourceFoldersToModel(aptOutputDir)
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            version = version
            artifactId = "your_artifact_id"
            groupId = "com.yourgroup.id"
            artifact(sourceJar)
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/libraryname-release.aar")
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            def releasesUrl = "releaseurl_ifavailable"
            def snapshotsUrl = "snapshoturl_ifavailable"
            url = version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsUrl : releasesUrl
            credentials {
                username = your_username
                password = your_password
            }
        }
    }
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
}
```

I was receiving these errors when I was trying to publish my library.

I already have solution and I will post it under the solution section.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.

Now my `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ...
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

version = '8.0.0'
android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
}

android.libraryVariants.all {
    def aptOutputDir = new File(buildDir, "generated/source/apt/${it.unitTestVariant.dirName}")
    it.unitTestVariant.addJavaSourceFoldersToModel(aptOutputDir)
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs
    archiveClassifier = "sources"
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                version = version
                artifactId = "your_artifactId"
                groupId = "com.yourgroup.id"
            }
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                def releasesUrl = "releaseurl_ifavailable"
                def snapshotsUrl = "snapshoturl_ifavailable"
                url = version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsUrl : releasesUrl
                credentials {
                    username = your_username
                    password = your_password
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I had to add an `afterEvaluate` tag for publication of the Android library.

Also, I removed the path from which the aar file would be published because `from components.release` does this for me.

I hope this helps people like me who were not able to find an answer to this particular problem.

Comment: where do you use `androidSourcesJar`  or `sourceJar`? I don't see for example `artifact androidSourcesJar` inside `maven(MavenPublication) {`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76565326/task-generatemetadatafileforreleasepublication-uses-this-output-of-task-androids here is my issue. what exactly should I change to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

[Mayank Pandit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10078504/mayank-pandit), you're right in your answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75951197/1071320)) to embed the `publishing` block within an `afterEvaluate` block and to replace the `artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/libraryname-release.aar")` declaration with `from components.release`.

If you compare the `build.gradle` files in your question and answer, you'll see that you've also removed the `artifact(sourceJar)` declaration. This means your Android library will now be published without its sources.

If you want to publish your Android library with its sources and supporting Javadoc, you need to make two changes to your `build.gradle` file, described below.

Firstly, add a `publishing` block within the `android` block as follows:

```
android {
  publishing {
    singleVariant("release") {
        withJavadocJar()
        withSourcesJar()
    }
  }
}
```

Secondly, change `maven(MavenPublication)` to `release(MavenPublication)`.

After making these two changes, you can get rid of the `sourceJar` task.

Refer to the [Android Gradle Plugin > Publish your library](https://developer.android.com/build/publish-library) documentation page for the latest guidance on how to publish your Android libraries.