# Task generateMetadataFileForReleasePublication uses this output of task androidSourcesJar without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, maven-plugin

The following command fails to publish my Android library:

```bash
./gradlew :my_sdk:publish --stacktrace
```

This is the error that I see:

```
Reason: Task ':my_sdk:generateMetadataFileForReleasePublication' uses this output of task ':my_sdk:androidSourcesJar' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
```

The contents of my `build.gradle` file which relate to publishing are the following:

```
task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                groupId mGroupId
                artifactId mArtifactId
                version mVersionName

                from components.release

                artifact androidSourcesJar

                pom {
                    name = mLibraryName
                    description = mLibraryDescription
                }
            }
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                name = "GitHubPackages"
                url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/HIDDEN_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW")
                credentials {
                    username = System.getenv("GPR_USER")
                    password = System.getenv("GPR_KEY")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Assembling should be performed before publishing package
publish.dependsOn assemble
```

It was working fine until I updated dependencies in the project (gradle plugin and so on).

Since getting the error, I tried updating the `afterEvaluate` block as follows:

```
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                ....
                // added this line here
                generateMetadataFileForReleasePublication.dependsOn androidSourcesJar
            }
        }
```

Now in Github Actions I get the following issue:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> > Task :my_module:generateMetadataFileForReleasePublication
>
> > Task :my_module:publishReleasePublicationToGitHubPackagesRepository FAILED
>
> - What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task
> ':my_module:publishReleasePublicationToGitHubPackagesRepository'. 0
> problems were found storing the configuration cache.
>
> > The following Gradle properties are missing for 'GitHubPackages' credentials:
>
> ```
> - GitHubPackagesUsername
> - GitHubPackagesPassword
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `artifact androidSourcesJar` declaration in your original `build.gradle` file (i.e. the one that doesn't have the `dependsOn` call) and add a `publishing` block within the `android` block as follows:

```
android {
  publishing {
    singleVariant("release") {
        withJavadocJar()
        withSourcesJar()
    }
  }
}
```

This will be enough to get rid of the error that you're seeing and to publish your Android library together with its sources.

You can go a step further and remove the `androidSourcesJar` task as well since you no longer need it.

Refer to the [Android Gradle Plugin > Publish your library](https://developer.android.com/build/publish-library) documentation page for the latest guidance on how to publish your Android libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and gradlew printed this note:

Possible solutions:

1. Declare task 'androidSourcesJar' as an input of 'generateMetadataFileForReleasePublication'.
2. Declare an explicit dependency on 'androidSourcesJar' from
   'generateMetadataFileForReleasePublication' using Task#dependsOn.
3. Declare an explicit dependency on 'androidSourcesJar' from 'generateMetadataFileForReleasePublication' using Task#mustRunAfter.

So I just added this line to my module's build.gradle and it seems to work fine:

```
afterEvaluate {
    generateMetadataFileForReleasePublication.dependsOn androidSourcesJar
}
```

Comment: thanks, will try it later and accept the answer

Comment: I get `> Could not get unknown property 'generateMetadataFileForReleasePublication' for project ':my_module_name' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: I use `id "maven-publish"` plugin (the newest naming for the latest gradle android plugin version)

Comment: Are you sure that you added it in "afterEvaluate" block? Maven-publish needs to be applied first, because it provides generateMetadataFileForReleasePublication task. After that you can make this task depend on androidSourcesJar.

Comment: of course, it's the main configuration

Comment: can you please provide full example of your module's build.gradle file?

Comment: The project is opened source so you can take a look. This is an example module's build.gradle file. I needed to add "afterEvaluate" block to each module.
https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-nRF-Connect-Device-Manager/blob/main/mcumgr-ble/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

it seems we have to add

```
GitHubPackagesUsername=
GitHubPackagesPassword=
```

to `gradle-wrapper.properties` with the latest maven plugin

otherwise it's not going to work